# Chain rule when the intermediary variable might be equal to zero

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, differentiation, calculus

I came across the following question in the kinematics section of my introductory physics textbook:

> The velocity of a particle moving along x-axis is given as $v=x^2-5x+4$ (in $m/s$), where $x$ denotes the x-coordinate of the particle in metres. Find the magnitude of the particle when the velocity of particle is zero?

And, this is the listed solution:

> $\begin{align}a&=\frac{dv}{dt}\\&=\frac{dv}{dx}\times\frac{dx}{dt}\\&=\frac{dv}{dx}\times v\\\end{align}$
>
> Putting $v = 0$,
>
> $\begin{align}a = \frac{dv}{dx} \times 0 = 0\ ms^{-2}\end{align}$

But, here's what I don't understand:
For the particular instant where $v=0$, $\begin{align}\frac{dx}{dt}=0\end{align}$. Consequently, the tiny change in $x$ i.e. $dx$ must also be $0$ (for that particular instant). Since we are dividing the change in velocity by the change in position in our solution, won't this make our expressions undefined?
$$dx=0 \implies \frac{dv}{dx}\times\frac{dx}{dt}=undefined$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of velocity in 1D.

$$v(t)=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{x(t)-x(t_0)}{t-t_0}=\frac{dx}{dt}$$

From this definition, you can recall that the limit does not say that $dx=0$. It only says that we are interested in the value that $\frac{x(t)-x(t_0)}{t-t_0}$ approaches when we get very close to $t_0$. In other words, $t$ gets close to $t_0$ but is not actually $t_0$. And, since $t\ne t_0$, it can't be that $x(t)=x(t_0)$ unless $x$ is the constant function. This corresponds to the slope of the tangent line to the curve.

The same can be said for $\frac{dv}{dx}$. The limit

$$\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{v(x)-v(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\frac{dv}{dx}$$

does not mean that $dx=0$, rather $x$ approaches $x_0$. If you are wondering why approaching does not mean reaching the value, it comes from the definition of the limit.

**Def.** Let $f:D\to R$ with $x_0$ a limit point of $D$. Then $f$ has a limit at $x_0$ if and only if for each $\epsilon >0$ there is a **$\delta >0$** such that if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ and $x\in D$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

it is the combination of $\delta >0$, $\epsilon >0$, $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, and $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ that does not permit $t$ to equal $t_0$ and $x(t)$ to equal $x(t_0)$ unless $x$ is the constant function. Even if $x$ constant, the definition of the limit will not allow $x=x_0$ for the $\frac{dv}{dx}$ term.

Answer (score 0):

In differential calculus, we deal with limits and dx is a infinitesimally small value but it is not zero,it approaches zero. So, we aren't dividing $$\frac{0}{0}$$ but instead
$$\frac{0.00000....1}{0.00000...1}$$ which is still valid and equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

The term $\frac{dv}{dx}$ is the slope of the velocity with respect to the position coordinate $x$. As we know $v = x^2 - 5*x + 4$ we calculate
$\frac{dv}{dx} = 2 x - 5$. In the following picture the derivative at $x_0=3$ is shown as red line.

[image]

In contrast $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is the slope of the position with respect to time $t$. This is the definition of the velocity $v$. From the question we know that this shall be zero. Hence, we put the two together and obtain
$$
a =  \frac{dv}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} 
= (2 x - 5) \cdot 0
$$
This is obviously zero.

Do not think of the "d" as tiny, but as slope.